# Pytorch warning displays despite being filtered

Tags: python, pytorch, warnings

I am fitting a dataset using the fastai library. The code causing the issue is here:

```
learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, TransformerXL, path='training_data')

with warnings.catch_warnings():

    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    learn.fit_one_cycle(epochs, 1e-2)
```

It throws a warning every step, despite the filter:

`Warning: masked_fill_ received a mask with dtype torch.uint8, this behavior is now deprecated,please use a mask with dtype torch.bool instead. (masked_fill__cuda at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/LegacyDefinitions.cpp:19)`

The code works, and I don't use pytorch directly, so I'd rather ignore the warning. In particular, the warning fills the console, preventing the epoch loss statistics from displaying. It looks like it's being handled by the standard library, so why doesn't the filter work? I have tried with and without the catch and both filters.

Comment: Got the same problem with "Warning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part (function operator ())". It only triggers once as it uses "TORCH_WARN_ONCE", but is it is still annoying.
 Did you ever find a solution?